# OnNext not called when disposing the result of Observable.subscribe

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm subscribing to an observable, but if I'm adding the disposable to the `DisposeBag` in my class, the `onNext` block is never called.

Here is my code :

```
@objc class AppleMusicPlaylistManager: NSObject {

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    let playlists: [MPMediaPlaylist] = []

    func importAppleMusicPlaylist() {
        playlists.forEach { applePlaylist in
            applePlaylist.getItunesStoreTracks().subscribe(onNext: { tracks in
               // Doing things here
            }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
        }
    }
}
```

where `getItunesStoreTracks` return a `RxSwift.Observable<[SoundsMusicITunesStore]>` and the whole thing is used like that `AppleMusicPlaylistManager().importAppleMusicPlaylist()`

Comment: since your `subscribe` return an `disposable` just assign it to some variable, then later on dispose it when your object get `deinit`

Comment: @Lamar from my understanding of RxSwift, it's exactly what `DisposeBag` is doing. Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all works as expected.

Current logic with `disposeBag` points out, that the observables will not be disposed of until the `disposeBag` is alive.

In your case - `AppleMusicPlaylistManager().importAppleMusicPlaylist()`, you create a manager and then you call the async requests, while the manager is deallocating. Thus all observables are deallocating as well.

In order for this to work correctly, you either have to set this manager as `shared` and use this method: `AppleMusicPlaylistManager.shared.importAppleMusicPlaylist()` or save this manager to some property in order to not deallocate immediately.